# Julia-lang - How to write to file in order

Tags: julia

For example, if I do (in Julia):
`f = open("out", "w"); write(f, 0x424d); close(f)`, the output of `xxd out` comes out to be: `00000000: 4d42 MB`
Why is it not in order? (`00000000: 424d BM`)

Comment: See Endianness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Little endian Vs Big endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247736/little-endian-vs-big-endian)

Comment: I considered endianness. How would I write with a custom endianness with Julia? I'm not talking about C

Comment: `f = open("out", "w"); write(f, 0x42); write(f,0x4d); close(f)`

Comment: Have you tried `reinterpret(Int16, read(f)))`? Also consider [`ntoh` and related functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/io-network/#Base.ntoh). And there's always the most portable method of just decomposing 0x424d into individual bytes and writing those in array format. (Later, you can read these and reinterpret followed by ntoh.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, Mateen Ulhaq pointed out this is a problem of endianness. The following might help you force the endianness of the processor on the file:

```
function dump_bytes(f,v)
  foreach(b->write(f,b),[unsafe_load(reinterpret(Ptr{UInt8},
    pointer_from_objref(v)),i) for i=1:sizeof(v)])
  return nothing
end

f = open("out","w")
dump_bytes(f,0x1234)
close(f)
```

For the reverse, i.e. force the endianness of the file on the processor, you can `reinterpret(Int16, read(f))` like Mateen's comment suggested.